# How do I import project settings from one Xcode project to another

Tags: xcode, ide, migration

I just upgraded my Xcode, and created a blank new project, and discovered that there's many new settings that don't exist in my old Xcode projects. As a result, when I build and run my old projects, I get weird warnings that I didn't before.

I think it's just a matter of having the good factory defaults that come with new projects. Is there an easy way for me to migrate to the new project settings.

Right now, I'm having to create a new empty project, and move (almost one-by-one), all my files and groups over to the new one, and re-stitching everything together.

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't you just use the old project instead of creating a new one? Where are you getting the files from? Also, what do you mean by "settings"?

Comment: By "settings" I mean "Build Settings." Why not just keep the old one? Because my project was created a year ago, and new blank projects in Xcode have maybe 5-8 different settings than I have, and so I'm wondering if I'm missing out on some optimizations that have happened over the past year.

Answer (score 3):

Use [xcconfig files](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360) rather than the build pane. You can also [build your own templates](http://robnapier.net/blog/project-templates-364). Some of this has changed in Xcode 4, but most still applies.